# OSX Package not running executable

Tags: xcode, macos, package, executable

I am new to development on OSX and am having an issue that is confusing me.

I am using xcode for work and I everything works when I debug from xcodes debugger.
However, when I am running the package manually, it doesn't seem to run the executable in the packages MacOS.

Basically, in xcode, is there something I need to set so that it knows where and how to run the executable in the MacOS directory?
I already changed the plist to have the executable set to the correct name. I am stuck as to even where to start looking for the issue.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give, developing for the mac has been a crash course for me :P
-Bear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Archive the project (Product->Archive) and then open the Organizer (Window->Organizer), select the archived version and click on "Distribute" and select "Export as Application".

Comment: Thanks, sorry this took so long to reply. I think that fixed it I changed some other settings but things seem to be working now.